# MediaStore Add Song to existing Album

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm trying to add my Audio files to MediaStore but I cannot seem to to find a way to add a Song to an existing Album. I tried fetching the Album_Id and setting it when adding the song and although an Id is present (> 0) it doesn't add the song to album . here's my code:

```
//fetch album id
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                 new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID},
                               MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM + "=?" +
                               " and " + MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST + "=?" ,
                 new String[] {albumName,albumArtistName},
                 MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM + " ASC");
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                 albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.
                 getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID));
                 cursor.close();
}

//create new song with the album_id if one exists
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, getName());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, getName());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, fileName);
String artistName = getArtist_name();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(albumArtistName))
          artistName = albumArtistName;
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, artistName);
if(albumId > 0){
          values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, albumId);
}
else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(albumName)){
          values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, albumName);
}
Uri base =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(fileName);
Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);
// Notifiy the media application on the device
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
```

Comment: Adding to mediastore yourself is futile as android scanning will do this automatically.

Comment: @Theo I need to provide metadata from an external source, the code above works however I found out mediastore is very picky about the folder where Data is located. so far the only way for  songs to be part of an album seems to be putting them in the same folder with the same album name.

Comment: I note that album_id is of type int in the audio_meta table.

Comment: I note that album_id is of type int in the audio_meta table. Your method appears to be correct. I use Razorsql on my pc to investigate databases structures. The media database you get using the android device monitor in Android Studio. Navigate to data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases and pull external.db to your pc. Then open with sql tool. This way you can check what it actually did update.

Comment: @Theo thanks a lot for the info. I'll try to see what happens inside. I thought merely setting the ID would set the album, as is the case in most databases. but it seems to be more complicated.